# Git on Windows not asking for SSH key password. SSH not found correctly id_rsa key

Tags: git, ssh

The problem is that I never see a prompt to enter my SSH-Key password, just a prompt that offers login directly to my git server.

Tested ssh connection:

```
$ ssh -vT git@myhost.lan
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to myhost.lan [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.<br>
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory<br>
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
...
```

What does `debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type "0"` mean?
When the key does not exist in directory type is "-1", when it does type should be "1"

My id_rsa key is located in

```
c:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa

$ ssh-add /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Key pair was generated with git-bash command `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C""`